# Why is for loop skipping part of string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, syntax

I am creating a calculator app that follows the order of operations. My issue is coming the else if on line 10 that checks for parentheses. What I want it to do it check for an open parentheses, run whats inside through my Calculator method recursively, push it into my parsed string array to be calculated again, remove the parentheses from my string, and then start i again at 0 to move the for loop to front of my string. For some reason it is skipping to the second parentheses and running it twice. Here is my code:

```
Calculator("(3*2)/(2+1)+4");
//Should get 3
function parseCalculationString(expression){
    let parsedString = [];
    for(i = 0; i<expression.length; i++){
        if(expression[i]!=" "){
            if (expression[i]>='0' && expression[i]<='9'){
                parsedString.push(parseFloat(expression[i]));
            }
            else if(expression[i] == '('){
                //let parentheses = Calculator(expression.split('(').pop().split(')')[0]);
                let subExpression = expression.split('(').pop().split(')')[0];
                console.log(subExpression)
                parsedString.push(Calculator(subExpression))
                console.log(parsedString)
                expression = expression.substring(expression.indexOf(')')+1)
                console.log(expression)
                i=0;
                
            }
            else{
                parsedString.push(expression[i]);
            }    
        }
        
    }
    return parsedString;
}
function Calculator(str) {  
  // code goes here
  let parsedExpression = parseCalculationString(str);
  const operations = ['*', '/', '+', '-']
  for (i = 0; i < operations.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < parsedExpression.length; j++){
        if(operations[i] == parsedExpression[j]){
            if(operations[i] == '*'){
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j-1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j-1]*parsedExpression[j+1]));
            }
            else if(operations[i] == '/'){
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j-1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j-1]/parsedExpression[j+1]));
            }
            else if(operations[i] == '+'){
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j-1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j-1]+parsedExpression[j+1]));
            }
            else if(operations[i] == '-'){
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j-1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j-1]-parsedExpression[j+1]));
            }
        } 
        
      }
  }
  
  str = parsedExpression[0];
  
  return str; 

}
```

And my output:

```
2+1 
(1) [3]
/(2+1)+4 
2+1 
+4
```

And my expected output:

```
3*2
[6]
/(2+1)+4
2+1
[6,/,3]
+4
```

Comment: Probably this part: `expression.split('(').pop()`. This splits your test expression into 3 pieces and grabs the last piece. You probably want `expression.split('(')[1]` instead.

Comment: Possibly post  your algorithm as well. You say recursion but i'm seeing circular reference. It's very hard to debug complex code without a guiding algorithm on the correct approach.

Comment: @GetSet I was saying recursion because I called Calculator while the process was still running in Calculator. I don't know if I am using that correctly. What is circular reference?

Comment: @Ouroborus That worked for the skipping.

Comment: Circular reference is when you call one function, and the function that you call, calls the caller. You do that here in your approach. `parseCalculationString` calls `Calculator` and vice versa. It's not a problem, per se. It's just apparently your approach.

Comment: If it were "recursion", then `Calculator()` would call itself. That doesn't appear to be the case in your question. No matter. As long as it works. But possibly, the "guiding algorithm" does indeed use recursion, where here you have circular reference. .... So this is partially why I recommended for you to include the algorithm in your question. The other reason would help for debugging other issues by the community.

Comment: Anyway, upvoting. Its a noble coding attempt on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    console.log("===>", Calculator("(3*2)/(2+1)+4"));
    //Should get 3
    function parseCalculationString(expression) {
        let parsedString = [];
        for (i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
            if (expression[i] != " ") {
                if (expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9') {
                    parsedString.push(parseFloat(expression[i]));
                }
                else if (expression[i] == '(') {
                    let subExpression = expression.split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
                    console.log(subExpression)
                    parsedString.push(Calculator(subExpression))
                    console.log(parsedString)
                    expression = expression.substring(expression.indexOf(')') + 1)
                    console.log(expression)
                    i = 0;
                }
                else {
                    parsedString.push(expression[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        return parsedString;
    }
    function Calculator(str) {
        // code goes here
        let parsedExpression = parseCalculationString(str);
        const operations = ['*', '/', '+', '-']
        for (i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < parsedExpression.length; j++) {
                if (operations[i] == parsedExpression[j]) {
                    if (operations[i] == '*') {
                        Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j - 1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j - 1] * parsedExpression[j + 1]));
                    }
                    else if (operations[i] == '/') {
                        Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j - 1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j - 1] / parsedExpression[j + 1]));
                    }
                    else if (operations[i] == '+') {
                        Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j - 1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j - 1] + parsedExpression[j + 1]));
                    }
                    else if (operations[i] == '-') {
                        Array.prototype.splice.apply(parsedExpression, [j - 1, 3].concat(parsedExpression[j - 1] - parsedExpression[j + 1]));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        str = parsedExpression[0];
        return str;
    }
</script>
```

// just updated the following line

```
let subExpression = expression.split('(').pop().split(')')[0];
```

to

```
let subExpression = expression.split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
```

Comment: (3*2*3)/(2+1)+4") !== 6

Comment: the correct way to solve expression is using infix to postfix conversion and then using a stack to evaluate it.

for this expression (3*2*3)/(2+1)+4, the problem is in Calculator() method, it needs 2 operands and 1 operator only. otherwise use ( ).

Comment: and one more thing, this code will not work if we use nested brackets.

Comment: Glad you noticed that @AshishTiwari on the nested brackets. The code needs more test cases to be completely debugged. I'm personally curious on the origin "algorithm".

Comment: I think that I solved it, please check it in my github https://github.com/daniil-loban/no_polish_notation_calculator/blob/main/index.js and put a star if you like it :) or write me about issue